# Dynamic property setter via expressions is not working

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

Hi I have following perfectly working code when I run it in console application but it fails in real app with exeption  "Specified cast is not valid."  at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object ), do any one knows that is root cause for this ?

```
    public class Base
    {

    }

    public class Test:Base
    {
        public string TestProp { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Base test = new Test();
        var prop=test.GetType().GetProperty("TestProp");
        var method = BuildSetAccessor(prop.SetMethod);
        method(test, "sa");
    }

    static Action<object, object> BuildSetAccessor(MethodInfo method)
    {

        var obj = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "o");
        var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));

        Expression<Action<object, object>> expr =
            Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(
                Expression.Call(
                    Expression.Convert(obj, method.DeclaringType),
                    method,
                    Expression.Convert(value, method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType)),
                obj, value);


        return expr.Compile();
}
```

Comment: Can you show class sample that doesn't work?

Comment: It will throw Specified cast isn't valid if you send in your example send `int` variable into your `TestProp` delegate. Then it will fail with such exception, as it has `string` property but it will get `int`

Comment: I pass a string into a string field, the sample what is now working is very simalar to this one but it burred inside layers of code I can't expose

Comment: Maybe there are some difference in inheritance\property types\overriding? Because it's hard to tell as this sample is working fine.

Comment: Just a hunch, but try `prop.GetSetMethod()` instead of `prop.SetMethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the answer at the moment, but I would recommend you to change your code to something like this:

```
static Action<TOb, TPar> BuildSetAccessor<TOb, TPar>(MethodInfo method)
{
    var obj = Expression.Parameter(method.DeclaringType, "o");
    var value = Expression.Parameter(method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType);

    if (method.GetParameters().Length > 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("Method with more than 1 parameters is not supported");

    LambdaExpression expr =
        Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Call(
                obj,
                method,
                value),
            obj, value);

    var compiled = expr.Compile();
    return new Action<TOb, TPar>((o, p) => compiled.DynamicInvoke(o, p));
}
```

And usage:

```
var method = BuildSetAccessor<Base, object>(prop.SetMethod);
method(test, "1");
```

I think this approach is better then casting parameters in LINQ query because generated exception info is more detailed.

Comment: Thank you it looks like your solution solved my problem , one question why did you added this line in the end new Action<TOb, TPar>((o, p) => compiled.DynamicInvoke(o, p)); ?

Comment: @MichaelT I'm happy to help! I used non-generic `ExpressionLambda` class. Its `Compile` method produces `Delegate` object, but you wanted a generic `Action` delegate in result, so I wrapped it.

Comment: Mmm, does that mean that I can get a bounty (it requires an extra action as I know)?